# (SQL) I have to use the IN operator to get information from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

this is my first year learning SQL so bear with me :)

A question in an assignment I was given is asking me this: "Use the IN operator to find the number and name of each customer that placed an order on October 12, 2015." So, here's what I tried using:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE ORDER_DATE IN
(SELECT ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDER_DATE = '12-OCT-15');
```

When I ran this code, I got an error:

> ORA-00904: "ORDER_DATE": invalid identifier
>
> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier

I've looked at the examples my professor provided in our notes and I've tried changing things around (that just gave an error about Literals). I need data from two different tables as CUSTOMER_NUM and CUSTOMER_NAME are in the Customer table and ORDER_DATE is in the Orders table (CUSTOMER_NUM is also in the Orders table)

Thanks for any help.
Sorry if this is a dumb question, I just don't know what to do from here :)

Let me know if I need to add more information from the data I'm using so you can help me.

Comment: So CUSTOMER_NUM are in both tables...

Comment: Is ORDER_DATE in the CUSTOMER table? If not, you must join CUSTOMER to ORDERS, probably on CUSTOMER_NUM

Comment: "CUSTOMER_NUM" is in both tables means you need to do your subquery and also your where clause of the main query based on this column instead of "ORDER_DATE". Furthermore, you likely need to change the way how you check the date. Which Db do you use?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, CUSTOMER_NUM is in both Customer and Orders tables

Comment: Krasi, it was a hint.

Comment: So, you want customers who's id's appear in the set of orders that occurred on that one date? (That's rhetorical, I'm trying to provide a hint so you can work it out yourself, as a learning aid.)

Comment: @JonasMetzler So instead of using ORDER_DATE in the first WHERE, I should use CUSTOEMR_NUM? I tried doing that and it gave me an error about Literals. Also, by Db do you mean what I'm using to program and whatnot? Cause I'm using Oracle SQL Developer as per my professor's request.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it seems I didn't see you already taged the DB. So when you use an Oracle DB, I think your date comparison is risky. Did you check if this is working?

Comment: @MatBailie Yeah, when I run the code I want the result to display the CUSTOMER_NUM and CUSTOMER_NAME based of orders only placed on 12-OCT-15
(looking at the data given by my professor, there are only 2 customers who placed an order on that date)

Comment: Then code literally what I wrote. I even used the word IN for you.

Comment: OKAY. I think I got it figured out, it ran and outputted exactly what I wanted. Thank you all for your helpful hints and information :)

I'm thinking, "it was really that easy?" right now. Oh well, we should be good now. This is my second time actually typing up SQL code. It's the little things that get me sometimes, haha. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ORDER_DATE IN ('12-OCT-15');` 
Try this

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the initial error stems from `where order_date in` predicate, as I would guess (even without table description) `order_date` does not exist in the `customer` table. Since use of IN is required it seems initial task is finding `customer_num` from the order table then accessing the customer table for the values found. **Not tested**.

```
select cust.customer_num, 
       cust.customer_name
 from customer cust
where cust.customer_num in 
      (select ord.customer_num 
         from orders ord
        where trunc(ord.order_date) = date '2015-08-12'
      );
```

**Notes:**

- Using the syntax `order_date in ('12-OCT-15')` is bad practice as it
  depends on implicit conversion and the setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  Instead employ explicit conversion `date 2015-08-12` (ISO date
  specification).
- In Oracle all date data types contain time components to the second.
  You use `trunc(<date_column>)` to strip off the time (actually set it
  to 00:00:00). The explicit conversion will also set time the same.
  This then allows accurate date=date comparison.
- DISTINCT is not required. The sub-query may return duplicates
  customers numbers, but the outer query will stop looking for a match
  when it hits the first one, so as long `customer_num` is unique in
  the customer table you will not get duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM, 
       CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM
WHERE ORDER.ORDER_DATE IN ('2015-10-12');
```

I'm used to POSTGRESQL so i'm not sure if this syntax will work with oracle but you get the point.

Comment: This is not the requested query, see the task: "Use the IN operator to find the number and name of each customer". You don't use the IN operator for that, but a JOIN. You do use an IN operator where it doesn't make sense since simply checking order_date = date_to_compare is much faster.

Comment: @JonasMetzler The question is totally not specific on how to use the IN operator so unless otherwise specifically stated, my answer is fine.

Comment: Also, if a customer made several orders on that date then they will appear in the results that many times, so this is Functionally flawed at present. (Using IN or EXISTS prevents that.)

Comment: @MatBailie alright then just use DISTINCT and problem solved.

Comment: not really, I'm confused at how you can even deduce what is actually needed from that very broad initial question. Though I'm sure there are better ways to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: The task could not be clear: "Use the IN operator to find the number and name of each customer that placed an order on October 12, 2015." And this exactly what you missed to do. Please don't argue in comments, that's not their purpose.

Comment: DISTINCT slows down the query which is not needed when following the task instead.

Comment: @JonasMetzler To me, the question is simply asking to identify all customers that made an order on october 12 2015 by using the IN operator. It does not specify how you should be using said operator.

Comment: Then you'd fail this assignment.

Comment: @MatBailie Please don't argue in comments, that's not their purpose

Comment: @CluelessDawg1337 Your handling of the date column is *almost correct*. Unlike Postgres date data types in Oracle always contain time. You can `trunc(<date column>)` to handle this (see my answer for complete statement)